# Bootstrap Icons not showing (Xamarin WebView)

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, webview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to load a html page in a Xamarin WebView (mono-touch) and whilst trying to display icons from Bootstrap, It displays fine when the html page is loaded in the Safari browser but the icon changes when loaded in a WebView.

My question is, how do I display the bootstrap icon in the WebView?

In Safari: 
[image]

In WebView:
[image]

Code:

```
<section>
    <div class="input-group col-lg-2">
        <span class="input-group-addon">   
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>   
        </span>
        <input type="text" readonly class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">   
             <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">GPS</button>   
        </span>
    </div>
</section>
```

Ive checked and everything is referenced properly.

Answer (score 0):

It might be solved by adding `glyphicon-nonescaped` class

Your new code will be :

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker glyphicon-nonescaped"></i>
```

Comment: Negative, doesn't seem to make any difference. Thanks for the effort though.